# MacOS/CMake - Unable to find package LZMA

Tags: cmake

I am running MacOS Ventura 13.5 on Apple M2 Max chip.

I have already executed:

```
☁  ~  brew install xz
Warning: xz 5.4.4 is already installed and up-to-date.
To reinstall 5.4.4, run:
  brew reinstall xz
☁  ~
```

and in my CMakeLists.txt I have this:

```
find_package(LZMA REQUIRED)
```

However I do get the following error:

```
CMake Error at Agent/CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindLZMA.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "LZMA", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LZMA" with any of
  the following names:

    LZMAConfig.cmake
    lzma-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "LZMA" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "LZMA_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LZMA"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

Looks like CMake can not find lzma even though I have it installed. Why is that and how can I fix it ?